# Relation of variance and energy of signal

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, signal-processing

The [total energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)) of a signal $g(t)$ is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g(t)|^2 dt$$
If the random variable $X$ has a probability density function $f(x)$, then its variance is
$${\displaystyle \operatorname {Var} (X)=\int _{\mathbb {R} }x^{2}f(x)\,dx-\mu ^{2},}$$
Is there a relation of variance and energy of signal if $\mu=0$? I ask this question why I found similar topics and questions on this forum (e.g. [What is the relationship between variance and energy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214563/what-is-the-relationship-between-variance-and-energy)). Moreover, on a [university webpage](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/st/Signal_Metrics.html) I read "We think of the variance as the power of the non-constant signal components". These sources did not help me to understand if there is a relation between variance and energy of signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will make the case for signals described as sequences of random variables. Let $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be our signal. We suppose that $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is [weakly stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity) (WS), and therefore has a stationary autocovariance function $(\gamma_X(\nu))_{\nu \in \mathbb{Z}}$. We further suppose that $E[X_k]=0,\,\forall k$ for simplicity (de-meaning leads more general cases to this case). The [power spectral density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density) (PSD) is (and sometimes is defined as) the Fourier transform of the autocovariance function:
$$S_X(\xi)=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\gamma_X(k)e^{-ik\xi}$$
The autocovariance function can be recovered from the PSD by [inverse FT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Inverse_transform):
$$\gamma_X(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}S_X(\xi)e^{ik\xi}d\xi$$
Now notice that $\gamma_X(0)=\sigma_X^2=E[X_k^2],\,\forall k$, that is, the zero lag autocovariance is the variance. But then
$$\sigma_X^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{(-\pi,\pi]}S_X(\xi)d\xi$$
So that the variance of a random WS signal is the *total power* of a signal. Mind variance makes real sense only when signals are random, in which case we must speak of *power* (an ergodic quantity of random signals) and not of *energy* (the $\ell^2$-integral of a deterministic signal in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$).

Answer (score -1):

Let $X$ be a random variable with a pdf (probability density function) $f_X(x)$, mean $\mu_X = E\{X\}$, and variance $\sigma_X^2 = E\{(X-\mu_X)^2\}$. Then the following relation holds :

$$ E\{X^2\} = E\{(X-\mu_x)^2\} + E\{X\}^2 = \sigma_X^2 + \mu_x^2 \tag{1}$$

In Eq.1, the LHS $E\{X^2\}$ is known as the *total power* of the R.V. $X$, whereas the terms $\sigma_X^2$ and $\mu_X^2$ are known as *AC* and *DC* powers respectively.